# Получить результат из функции в Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Есть функция main, которая обращается за результатом к функции Checker.
 При выполнении скрипта, никаких сообщений из Cheker не выводится и не пишется "Все ОК", хотя файлы существуют и имеют права на чтение.
Что я делаю не так?

```
 #!/bin/bash
    file1="$1"
    file2="$2"
    main()
    {   
            if  [ "$(checker)" == "true" ]
            then
                    echo "Все ОК"
            fi
    }
    checker()
    {
            flag=""
            if [ -f "$file1" ] && [ -f "$file2" ]
            then
                    echo "Файлы существуют"
                    if [ -r "$file1" ] && [ -r "$file2" ]
                    then
                            echo "Файлы могут быть прочитаны"
                            flag="true"
                    else
                            echo "Один из файлов не может быть прочитан"
                            flag= "false"
                    fi

            else
                    echo "Один из файлов не существует"
                    flag="false"
            fi

            echo "$flag"

    }
main
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Из двух функций сделайте одну с проверкой по `$flag`
2. Откройте для себя `return [N]` вместо `flag`

Answer (score 2):

> Что я делаю не так?

располагаете функцию до её вызова.

перенесите функцию `main` в конец файла — и, скорее всего, вы получите ожидаемый результат.

Comment: Получается тоже самое... Если поменять скобки                                     if  (( checker == "true")), то я получаю нужный результат, но опять же... почему-то не пишутся сообщения из checker...

Comment: Как мне сделать так, что бы функцию возвращала true или false, а так же печатала информацию типа "Файлы существуют" и т п?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

file1="$1"
file2="$2"

checker() {
    flag=""
    if [ -f "$file1" ] && [ -f "$file2" ]
        then
        echo "Файлы существуют"
            if [ -r "$file1" ] && [ -r "$file2" ]
                then
                echo "Файлы могут быть прочитаны"
                flag=true
            else
                echo "Один из файлов не может быть прочитан"
                flag=false
            fi
        else
    echo "Один из файлов не существует"
    flag=false
    fi
echo $flag
}
checker
main() {
        if [[ $(checker) == *true ]]
            then
                    echo "Все ОК"
            fi
    }
main
```